# How to calculate No of cores,executors, amount of memory in Spark Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can someone help me in finding the no of cores,executors,memory ..etc in spark.

I am using open source apache spark cluster

below is my configuration -

```
Total 6 nodes(1 master and 5 slaves). 
32GB per node
16 vCPUS per node
```

Note - seems like master node is not participating in computation, that's how cluster setup.

```
--driver-memory = ?

--executor-memory =? 

--executor-cores =?

--num-executors =?
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you to answer on the basis of below configuration

**Distribution of Executors, Cores and Memory for a Spark Application running in Yarn:**

Now, let’s consider a 10 node cluster with following config and analyse different possibilities of executors-core-memory distribution:

- **Cluster Config:**

10 Nodes
16 cores per Node
64GB RAM per Node

- First Approach:

Tiny executors [One Executor per core]:
Tiny executors essentially means one executor per core. Following table depicts the values of our spar-config params with this approach:

- `--num-executors` = In this approach, we'll assign one executor per core
  = total-cores-in-cluster
  = num-cores-per-node * total-nodes-in-cluster
  = 16 x 10 = 160
- `--executor-cores` = 1 (one executor per core)
- `--executor-memory` = amount of memory per executor
  = mem-per-node/num-executors-per-node
  = 64GB/16 = 4GB
  Analysis: With only one executor per core, as we discussed above, we’ll not be able to take advantage of running multiple tasks in the same JVM. Also, shared/cached variables like broadcast variables and accumulators will be replicated in each core of the nodes which is 16 times. Also, we are not leaving enough memory overhead for Hadoop/Yarn daemon processes and we are not counting in ApplicationManager. NOT GOOD!
- Second Approach:

Fat executors (One Executor per node):
Fat executors essentially means one executor per node. Following table depicts the values of our spark-config params with this approach:

- `--num-executors` = In this approach, we'll assign one executor per node
  = total-nodes-in-cluster
  = 10
- `--executor-cores` = one executor per node means all the cores of the node are assigned to one executor
  = total-cores-in-a-node
  = 16
- `--executor-memory` = amount of memory per executor
  = mem-per-node/num-executors-per-node
  = 64GB/1 = 64GB
  Analysis: With all 16 cores per executor, apart from ApplicationManager and daemon processes are not counted for, HDFS throughput will hurt and it’ll result in excessive garbage results. Also,NOT GOOD!
- Third Approach:

Balance between Fat (vs) Tiny
According to the recommendations which we discussed above:

Based on the recommendations mentioned above,
Let’s assign 5 core per executors => `--executor-cores` = 5 (for good HDFS throughput)

Leave 1 core per node for Hadoop/Yarn daemons => Num cores available per node = 16-1 = 15

So, Total available of cores in cluster = 15 x 10 = 150

Number of available executors = (total cores/num-cores-per-executor) = 150/5 = 30

Leaving 1 executor for ApplicationManager => --num-executors = 29

Number of executors per node = 30/10 = 3

Memory per executor = 64GB/3 = 21GB

Counting off heap overhead = 7% of 21GB = 3GB. So, actual --executor-memory = 21 - 3 = 18GB

So, recommended config is: 29 executors, 18GB memory each and 5 cores each!!

Analysis: It is obvious as to how this third approach has found right balance between Fat vs Tiny approaches. Needless to say, it achieved parallelism of a fat executor and best throughputs of a tiny executor!!

Conclusion:
We’ve seen:

Couple of recommendations to keep in mind which configuring these params for a spark-application like:
Budget in the resources that Yarn’s Application Manager would need
How we should spare some cores for Hadoop/Yarn/OS deamon processes
Learnt about spark-yarn-memory-usage
Also, checked out and analysed three different approaches to configure these params:
Tiny Executors - One Executor per Core
Fat Executors - One executor per Node
Recommended approach - Right balance between Tiny (Vs) Fat coupled with the recommendations.
--num-executors, --executor-cores and --executor-memory.. these three params play a very important role in spark performance as they control the amount of CPU & memory your spark application gets. This makes it very crucial for users to understand the right way to configure them. Hope this blog helped you in getting that perspective

Detail analysis can be found on below link
https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html